# .Net CIL jmp opcode and generic methods

Tags: .net, cil

I'm trying to see how to use the `jmp` opcode and so far I didn’t manage to call generic methods yet. For my tests, I'm having one method which just returns its argument and another whose body is only the `jmp` opcode jumping to the first method. My problem is that when I jump to a non-generic method (e.g. `jmp int32 Program::Id2(int32)` with the following signature for Id2: `static int Id2(int x)`) there's no error at runtime, while if I do so for a generic method (e.g. `jmp !!0 Program::Id<int32>(!!0)` with the following signature for Id: `static T Id<T>(T x)`) I get a “Common Language Runtime detects an invalid program” exception. What could be the cause of that problem?

*P.S. :* Here’s [a gist](https://gist.github.com/Bebere/75c95d9993505a40667b0b35a5afeeef) with the CIL I was using for my tests. Commenting the line jumping to `Id2` and uncommenting the one jumping to `Id` in `IdInt` makes it fail at runtime with the aforementioned exception. Making `IdInt` and `Id2` return a reference type like `StringBuilder` doesn’t make it fail though.

Comment: Can you post a compilable example?

Comment: @thehennyy Good point, I added a gist with my test IL.

Comment: Have you tried running peverify on your code?

Comment: @svick The `jmp` instruction is never verifiable.

Comment: !!0 is a place-holder for the first generic type parameter.  Basic problem is that there isn't one, you used the JMP in a non-generic method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ECMA-335 partition III section 3.37 - jmp, says:

> Transfer control to the method specified by method, which is a metadata token (either a methodref or
>   methoddef (See Partition II). The current arguments are transferred to the destination method.

Both MemberRef and MethodDef tokens are able to reference non-generic methods and open generic methods, but to reference a closed generic method requires a MethodSpec token which is not listed as acceptable.

I suspect that jmp might not support generic methods because it would interfere with the jits ability to reuse native code for different instantiations of the same generic method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it's indeed probably because I'm jumping to a closed generic method: this [second gist](https://gist.github.com/Bebere/6240be508093f51e0647a9649c8bae2c) which jumps to an open generic method works.

Comment: You are not using an open generic method in that second gist, the type argument you pass to it is coming from Id2. This means that my answer is incorrect (ill investigate and update later when I have more time). I suspect the real answer is that information about the set of type arguments is being passed from caller to callee like other arguments and the runtime needs to ensure that `Id` will correctly interpret the type arguments inherited from the call to `Id2`.